# Implementación de la autorización basada en roles mediante ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Me gustaría implementar una autorización basada en roles en mi aplicación web que estoy construyendo

Mi base de datos seria de esta manera donde idrol seria mi identificador de  rol de usuario ya sea al momento que se registren ya sea como coordinador,administrador,profesor o estudiante :

```
 create table registro(id int IDENTITY(1,1),Nombre varchar(100),appaterno varchar(100),apmaterno varchar(100),correo varchar(100),usuario varchar(100) PRIMARY KEY ,clave varchar(100),imagen image,idrol varchar(100));
```

y hago un select from donde me logeo con sesion

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataReader dr;
    // GET: Account
    [HttpGet]
   

    void connectionString()
    {
        con.ConnectionString =  "data source=DESKTOP-1F15CUB;database=master;integrated security=SSPI;";

    }
 


  public ActionResult Login(Registro1 acc)
    {
        connectionString();
        con.Open();
        com.Connection = con;
        com.CommandText =
 "select* from registro where usuario='"
 + acc.usuario +"'and clave='"+acc.clave+ "'";
         dr = com.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
       
            Session["usuario"] = Convert.ToString(acc.usuario);//acceso por sesion


            
            con.Close();//../Login/Login
            return View("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            con.Close();
         
            Response.Write("<script>alert('usuario no existente')</script>");
            //onclick="alert('clave incorrecta')"
            return View("Login");
        }
    }
```

y asi mando a llamar al metodo Login en una pagina login.cshtml

```
 <form action="Login" method="post">
               
                        <div class="input-group form-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="usuario" placeholder="usuario">

                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group form-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="clave" placeholder="contraseña">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row align-items-center remember">
                            <input type="checkbox">Recuerdame
                        </div>


                        <!-- checar video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BnJ8UI-tI-E -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <!-- <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">¿Soy un botón o un enlace?</a>-->
                            <!--<button type="button" class="btn float-right login_btn" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Opciondeacceso")'">Iniciar Sesion</button>-->
                            <input type="submit" value="Ingresar" class="btn float-right login_btn">
                        </div>
                   
                    </form>
```

hasta el momento le eh puesta esta funcion en mi index.cshtml pero no funciona la parte de permitir o prohibir el acceso a vistas =(

```
@if (User.IsInRole("admi"))

{

  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>Getting started</h2>
    <p>
        ASP.NET MVC gives you a powerful, patterns-based way to build dynamic websites that
        enables a clean separation of concerns and gives you full control over markup
        for enjoyable, agile development.
    </p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301865">Learn more 
    &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    </div>
    }

@if (User.IsInRole("coordi"))
{

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Getting started</h2>
        <p>
                    ASP.NET MVC gives you a powerful, patterns-based way to build dynamic websites 
                    that enables a clean separation of concerns and gives you full control over 
                    markup
                    for enjoyable, agile development.
              </p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301865">Learn 
             more &raquo;</a></p>
           </div>
          </div>


          }


      @if (User.IsInRole("profesor")){
    
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
       <h2>Getting started</h2>
         <p>
        ASP.NET MVC gives you a powerful, patterns-based way to build dynamic websites that
        enables a clean separation of concerns and gives you full control over markup
        for enjoyable, agile development.
       </p>
       <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301865">Learn more 
       &raquo;</a></p>
       </div>
       </div>

         }



        @if (User.IsInRole("estudiante"))

        {

      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Getting started</h2>
            <p>
                    ASP.NET MVC gives you a powerful, patterns-based way to build dynamic websites 
                     that enables a clean separation of concerns and gives you full control over 
                     markup  for enjoyable, agile development.
            </p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301865">Learn 
            more &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
           </div>

           }
```

pero mi duda es ¿Cómo permito o prohíbo el acceso a vistas / controladores específicos dentro de mi aplicación .NET MVC en una vista index.cshtml?

Answer (score 0):

En el Index del controlador puedes hacer la comprobación de roles y redirigir en caso de que no tenga permiso.

```
public ActionResult Index()    
{         
    if (!User.IsInRole("coordi"))    
    {    
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");    
    }
    return View(); 
}
```